# Updating all packages to latest results in error 'update' is not recognizable

Tags: node.js, npm

Trying to update all my packages listed in package.json file to their latest.
Specifically angular from 2.4.x to 4.3.x

I run this

```
npm update -D && update -S
```

and get this.  not sure what im stepping on here

```
'update' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're running two different commands, `npm update -D` and `update -S`, and you're connecting them with [`&&`](https://htipe.wordpress.com/2009/07/19/multiple-commands-on-a-single-windows-command-line/) which means "only run the second command if the first one completes successfully".  `npm update` succeeds, so cmd.exe tries to run `update -S`.  And since `update` isn't a known program, you get that error message.

You probably meant to type `npm update -D && npm update -S` (notice the extra `npm` in there).

Comment: yes, that was it.  however, I still have issues with the updates not working, but that was the problem with what I was trying to do - i was missing the extra npm command